# Xcode Table View cell twitter

Tags: uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.3

I just downloaded Xcode 4.4 and just started learning app development. I want to make a table view with rows that are divided into sections like the second row in the Twitter app like in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGFkl.jpg
I'm using storyboard. I looked on youtube and through some books, but have had no luck. Another question while I at it. Since I'm using storyboard, what do I do with the AppDelegates? I'm not fully sure what these are for and how to use them with storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit hope this is what you are looking for.